A geometric construction of parabola through 4 points
Ten years ago someone made a user's toolbox for Geometer's sketchpad software. After analyzing a user's tool for conic sections, I was surprised that the following construction of the parabola through 4 points seems to differ from the construction in Heinrich Dörrie's book.


Rotate $ CB $ around $ C $ by $ \angle DCA $, and rotate $ AB $ around $ A $ by $ \angle DAC $. The two lines intersect at $ E $.

Let $ O $ be the circumcircle of $ \triangle ABC $

Let $ N $ be a moving point on a tangent to circle $ O $ passing through $ E $.

Rotate $ CB $ around $ C $ by $ \angle NCA $, and rotate $ AB $ around $ A $ by $ \angle NAC $. The two lines intersect at $ F $.


Then the locus of $ F $ is a parabola passing through four points $ A, B, C, $ and $ D $.


How do you prove this?

About the number of solutions:
In Heinrich Dörrie's book it was shown that the construction is possible if and only if $A,B,C,D$ form a convex quadrilateral. In this case there are two parabolas through them.
In the above construction, Step 3 is possible if and only if $E$ is outside the circle $O$. So I think this condition should be equivalent to that $A,B,C,D$ form a convex quadrilateral, am I right?
If $E$ is outside circle $O$, there are two tangents from $E$ to the circle $O$, so we get two parabolas.

This construction follows from a nice property of isogonal conjugation:

The isogonal conjugate of a line with respect to triangle $ABC$ is a
conic passing through $A$, $B$ and $C$; specifically, an ellipse,
parabola, or hyperbola according as the line intersects the
circumcircle of $ABC$ in $0$, $1$, or $2$ points.

Here's then how it works.

We construct the isogonal conjugate $E$ of point $D$ with respect to $ABC$.

As $D$ lies on the parabola we want to find, point $E$ must belong to its isogonal conjugate, i.e. a line tangent to the circumcircle of $ABC$.

We construct then one such tangent $EN$ and take an arbtrary point $N$ on it.

We construct the isogonal conjugate $F$ of point $N$ with respect to $ABC$. Point $F$ belongs then to the parabola.


In my opinion this is not a real construction of the parabola, which would entail finding focus and directrix. But it can be handy with GeoGebra, for a fifth point $F$ of the parabola enables using the built-in tool "Conic through five points".
EDIT.
About the number of solutions: if $D$ lies inside triangle $ABC$, or inside the three angles formed by the extensions of its sides, then the isogonal conjugate of $D$ lies inside the circumcircle of $ABC$ and no tangent line can be constructed. Hence the condition that point $E$ be outside the circumcircle is indeed equivalent to $ABCD$ being a convex quadrilateral.
